# pytorch repeat 3rd dimension

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor

I'm following this example on [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat)

```
In [42]: x = torch.tensor([1,2,3])


In [45]: x.repeat(4,2)
Out[45]: tensor([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]])

In [46]: x.repeat(4,2).shape 
Out[46]: torch.Size([4, 6])
```

So far, so good.

But why does repeating just 1 time on 3rd dimension expand 3rd dim to 3 (not 1)?

```
[On the doc]

>>> x.repeat(4, 2, 1).size()
torch.Size([4, 2, 3])
```

Double checking.

```
In [43]: x.repeat(4,2,1)
Out[43]:
tensor([[[1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3]],

        [[1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3]],

        [[1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3]],

        [[1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3]]])
```

Why does it behave this way?

Comment: updated my answer with more details

Answer (score -1):

It expands the size([3]) tensor it only once along first dim. The (4,2,1) is the number of times you want to repeat a (3,) tensor. So, the final tensor is (4,2,3), because you repeat the (3,) once over last axis, twice over second last and 4 times over the first axis.

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
x.shape
```

```
torch.Size([3])
```

Then,

```
xx = x.repeat(4,2,1)
xx.shape
```

```
torch.Size([4, 2, 3])
```

Comment: are you saying when repeating, always start duplicating from the larger dim?

Comment: I am saying that the first dimension is the outer most bracket while the last dimension will contain the original array. Imaging a 1-D tensor - ```[1,2,3]```. Making this a 2-D array is simply adding brackets outside - ```[[1,2,3]]``` and its shape is ```(1,3)``` . Next making this a 3D- array - ```[[[1,2,3]]]``` and its shape is ```(1,1,3)```. This should give you intuition as to why repeating it in the above way results in a ```(4,2,3)```.

Comment: not sure why this answer if downvoted. this correctly answers the question OP has asked. with a detailed explanation both in the answer and the question.